# Including jar file to the php project which uses cpanel

Tags: java, linux, cpanel

I have completed a project in php. And hosted in server using cPanel.However I now need to include a jar file that just takes some parameter and produce some output.Is it possible to do so in cPanel. Where every other code has been written in php?

Comment: cpanel is an administration tool. what does that have to do with a .jar file? what do you mean by including a .jar file?

Answer (score 0):

PHP is a completely separate language from Java. The last time I used a cPanel host, you could not directly. But, if you can login to the server without using cPanel, you could start a separate Java server running on a different (not port 80) port. And you could modify the apache configuration to forward certain URLs there using [mod_proxy](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html), here's a [eHow](http://www.ehow.com/how_6108865_configure-apache-reverse-proxy.html).

Comment: you don't need a java server to run a .jar file. A simple `java -jar` should do. Assuming, of course, that the .jar is not a web application.

Comment: @eis How does that "embed" it in php? As long as it's a self-contained executable jar you're right that it will be running on the cpanel host.

Comment: If it "just takes some parameter and produce some output", you don't need to special embedding to do that, simple shell execution (shell_exec in php) would suffice. But yes, that's why I asked OP clarification about including.